# When a stock held in an IRA takes a downturn, is that a good time to move that asset to a Roth IRA?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, roth-ira, missouri

I have some traditional IRA funds invested in QuantumScape, and it's down quite a bit since the initial purchase. I want to continue to have some holdings in the company. Would this be a good time to move this stock to my Ruth IRA?

The question presupposes it won't lose much more value. My question is primarily about the tax implications if it's moved now vs. when it's higher.

Additionally, I'd like to understand what I pay taxes on. I would only pay taxes on an increase in value, correct? So since I've lost money on QuantumScape, I could move another stock that's gained money such that they roughly offset, and the taxes would be minimized, correct?

Comment: You can typically convert the shares directly into the Roth, without selling and rebuying them.

Comment: @aganju thanks, that would be better.

Comment: Reworded accordingly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All transactions inside the IRA are without tax relevance. You can buy and sell as much as you want, you never owe taxes (and never get deductions).

Taxes only apply when money moves *out* of the IRA, be it into the Roth or into your pocket. At that time, the full amount is considered taxable income.

Yes, it is a good idea to convert to Roth at a low price - it might be hard to guess the lowest day, but you can try to time it, and it’s to your advantage if you manage to.
I always do that; whenever there are some bad days in a row, I convert some shares.

Comment: So I'd actuality pay taxes on the value of the stock, right?

Comment: @HarryUnderbridge that depends on your IRA basis

Answer (score 1):

> I would only pay taxes on an increase in value, correct?

You'll pay taxes (and possibly penalties) on whatever money is taken out of the IRA.

Note that you can't typically move "stock" between IRA accounts - only cash. You'd get the same effect by selling the stock in your IRA, doing a rollover (or just contributing) in that amount to your Roth, and then buying the stock in the Roth. You'd still pay tax on the amount that you rollover, whether or not it funded by a gain or loss in the account.

Comment: +1 but to forestall JoeTaxpayer's inevitable counterexample, if the Traditional and Roth IRAs  have the same IRA custodian, it _might_ be possible to ask the custodian to just transfer the stock shares from the Traditional IRA to the Roth IRA. The transaction would be _recorded_ as if the stock shares were sold at the closing price of the day when the transfer occurred, the cash rolled over into the Roth IRA, and the shares promptly bought in the Roth IRA at the closing price; all without  any _actual_ selling and buying of shares (and hence no brokerage fees for the two stock transactions).

Comment: Vanguard allows such in-stock conversions. I have done many (one today, btw, as prices are low)

Comment: I transferred securities today. Both accounts are in TD Ameritrade. There were no fees since these are IRAs.